# how to force all centos terminal dns queries to squid proxy?

Tags: linux, docker, dns, squid

Is there a way how to define my nameserver to use a proxy in /etc/resolv.conf?

Our DNS server is offline and has no direct connection to the internet, the only way to the internet is by using a proxy.

We're running a docker image that requires DNS requests to 8.8.4.4 and it's not taking the proxy for the query. I've set http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x, however, it's not working for DNS queries.

Answer (score -1):

Squid do not proxied DNS queries. It is not support it. 
You should setup custom DNS server on Squid host and configure your CentOS to use it.